# Most Efficient Way To Search For The Corresponding Object?

Tags: python, pip, logic, command-line-interface

I am working on a package that makes installing other packages incredibly easy, inspired by homebrew but, hopefully, a bit better in terms of user-friendliness.

My goal:
To search through thousands of packages in order to find the correct one and then get the corresponding commands to install it.

Methods I've thought about:

1. Using if statements

```
def install(package_name):
    if package_name == 'something':
        # Install a package called something
    if package_name == 'nothing':
        # Install a package called nothing
```

2. Using a dictionary

Basically, there is a massive dictionary with key-value pairs, for example:

```
{'something', 'code to install something', 'nothing', 'code to install nothing'}
```

My question is, as this dictionary of packages gets bigger, which one of these is better and also, what is the best method to do the same thing other than these two?

Thanks and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: please look at the existing solutions and save yourself a ton of time. Both approaches won't work, because there is a ton of special cases to handle and simple key-value storage (dict is a perfect one) won't be enough.

Comment: any suggestions @Marat?

Comment: depends on the target platform(s), both hardware and software, the nature of the software to be handled, how you want to handle dependencies and **a lot** of other factors.